# Why should moderators delete my comments leaving others' comments?

Tags: discussion

I know we are not supposed to have extended discussions using comments. The linked question and its answer, [If comments are not for extended discussion, why do seasoned users use them for this?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2875/if-comments-are-not-for-extended-discussion-why-do-seasoned-users-use-them-for) are specifically about this issue.

Now, please take a look at the comments under the question, [English native speaker vs. Native English speaker](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/81173/english-native-speaker-vs-native-english-speaker).

Most of my comments were deleted while the other party's comments were not. Why?

I have given reasonable examples/explanations and context to support my argument that there is little chance people would be confused between **native English speaker** and **native speaker of English**. Where are my comments?

I think if you (moderators) need to delete the comments, you should delete all of them, not delete just a part of them. I don't think it is fair. I have the right to be wrong and I have the right to defend my point of view even if it is wrong.

I want your opinion on this issue. Is it fair to delete just one user's comments while leaving others? Was it not constructive? It was. Was it offensive? Never.

Comment: I try not to get too attached to my comments. Some of the other SE sites I participate on are much more aggressive in removing comments. Here, I think most are left along unless someone flags them or a moderator notices them and feels they aren't constructive. I think in general it's better to move discussions to chat like the moderators over on the Workplace SE often do. It makes "cleaning up" the question seem less punitive. I don't know what your comments contained, but maybe the moderator felt they were repetitive. I don't see many repeated comments by the same person there.

Comment: @ColleenV I agree. I don't care about comments as long as they are all deleted altogether or they are not deleted at all. Who cares? This is not the first time that our moderators have shown unfairness in terms of deleting comments. I would never do that if I were a moderator.

Comment: I think it is necessary though and I don't fault the moderators for trying to preserve the best parts of the discussion. For language learning it seems to me that the discussion in the comments is important to understanding the nuance of a question. Yes it would be better to have it all in an answer, but we have to live with reality. I think it is better that the conversation be edited than deleted entirely or left in a long confusing thread that might not get read at all.

Comment: It looks like the moderator left the comments with your point intact and just removed the ones that didn't contribute more to the discussion. It's not constructive to go on and on, tit-for-tat when it's obvious there will be no meeting of minds.

Comment: @ColleenV The other party left the first comment with his/her point in the first comment. I am not saying I don't understand it. The English language itself is flawed. It is never clear if you want to be such a pedant. Why should only my comments be deleted while the other comments are not? Don't you think it is fair to delete all of them if you  find the thread is too long or just repeating what has been said? I am talking about fairness. I am not defending the tit-for-tat thread or my arguments.

Comment: Other folks comments might have been deleted too. When I read that thread, it doesn't look to me like you are having your voice unfairly suppressed while other folks aren't. I don't see more than two comments from any poster except you. I know it's difficult to stop in the middle of a debate, but further debate isn't going to be helpful. So, yes, it was fair that all of the comments got trimmed down to the minimum needed to show the different points and I don't think it matters whether more of yours were deleted than someone else's. The content is what matters. Debates should happen in chat.

Comment: @ColleenV - You are correct on all counts: (1) Rathony's comments were **not** the only comments deleted; (2) not **all** of Rathony's comments were deleted; only the ones that made the discussion overly lengthy and contentious; (3) other users had fewer comments deleted because other users were more judicial in their comments; (4) you summarized it well: an effort was made to preserve the gist of the discussion while trying to keep it from becoming too lengthy.

Answer (score 13):

This is not a matter of fairness, this is a matter of balance.

If you don't want your comments deleted, then don't belabor the quibbling, don't be rude, and know when it's time to let the matter rest.

Most often, comments get deleted after someone's comment has been flagged for being too chatty, not constructive, or rude. Even then, not every flagged comment gets deleted. Each flag and each comment is evaluated by the moderation team. We do our best to act in a manner that is fair and in the best interest of the community.

Comment: I don't think your answer is fair. Show me some evidence in any of the deleted comments that were considered rude.

Comment: @Rathony - I didn't say your comments were rude. My answer is aimed at anyone who wouldn't want their comments deleted, and I listed several possible reasons a comment might get deleted.

Comment: Related (from SE meta): **Comments are temporary, ephemeral things, they are not a "discussion thread" or a place for debate. If a moderator feels a comment isn't helping the post (whether it's true or not, and whether it's offensive or not) the comment will be removed. Don't badger another answerer to change their answer to match your opinion.** (Kate Gregory) **Comments are deleted for a lot of reasons, such as a discussion or argument in the comments. Since comments can be deleted for just about any reason, we may not always see the connection between deletions.** (George Stocker)

Comment: I wonder if including the qualities of comments that get preserved, i.e. "Dos" instead of "Don'ts", would be helpful. It's hard to look at the response I'm writing to someone who didn't "understand" my point (because of course if they had understood it, they would agree with me! :) ) and think "Oh, this is probably quibbling, I shouldn't post it." It's more likely that I would look at it and think "This doesn't add anything new to the discussion, so it's probably not a great comment."

Comment: @ColleenV - I think my answer already addresses some of the other do's and don'ts: too chatty, not constructive, etc. Perhaps the best "Do's & Don'ts" guidance might be found in the standard SE [Be Nice](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) post. Moreover, you summed it up well with your initial comment: don't get "too attached" to your comments. Bottom line is that comments don't need to be "not nice" to be removed.